# Why isn't this possible: let array[j] = array[j] + 1;

Tags: javascript, arrays

If word is present inside array. Create variable that stores the amount of times that word happens inside array. When I run this I get the error Unexpected token. If newStory[i] is equal to overusedWords[j] create a variable overusedWords[j] and add +1 to it.

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';
let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically']
const newStory = story.split(" ");

//Here we find the number of times overusedWords are used specifically in story
for (let i = 0; i <= newStory.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j <= overusedWords.length; j++){
 if(newStory[i] === overusedWords[j]){
   let overusedWords[j] = overusedWords[j] + 1;
 };
  };
};
```

Comment: toxic-overflow, hahahahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because every element within the `overusedWords` array is a string. `overusedWords[j] + 1` is simply string concatenation, and will not do anything useful that will achieve your objective.

The iteration for the element 'every' will only result in this: 'really11'.

Please do something like this instead:

```js
const story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';
const overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

const result = {};

const newStory = story.split(" ");

for (let i = 0; i < newStory.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < overusedWords.length; j++){
    if(newStory[i] === overusedWords[j]){
      if (result.hasOwnProperty(overusedWords[j])) {
        result[overusedWords[j]] = result[overusedWords[j]] + 1;
      } else {
        result[overusedWords[j]] = 1;
      }       
    };
  };
};

console.log(result);
```

Basically, we create an object that stores the number of times each of the keywords appear within that `story`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out, but I have one question. Is there a way for me to do the following. 
If word !== overusedWords, create variable and add 1 to it?

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic you mean, you want to check if the word in `story` does not exist in the `overusedWords` array? Because right now this if condition checks if `(newStory[i] === overusedWords[j])`  the word exists in the `overusedWords` array

Comment: Hm, actually, I like the way you've solved my problem, but is there a way to avoid using the const result, can I just loop through an array instead of writing every word like you did?

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic Glad to help! What do you mean by that? avoid the const result? and,'just loop through an array instead of writing every word like you did'?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how would someone go about writing this more elegantly? What if I had 100 or 1000 overusedWords that I wanted to check. The const result thing would be incredibly long and take up extremely much space.

Comment: Alright! I have edited my code. I initialised an empty `result` object, and within the for loop, I used `hasOwnProperty()` to check if the keyword exists in the object. If it doesnt, it will add that new property to the object, with a value of 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can not create variable with name contain [ character

You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.

A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

```
let overusedWords[j] = overusedWords[j] + 1;
```

You can change to `overusedWords[j] = overusedWords[j] + 1;` for update array `overusedWords` at j index.

Also in your code should only check `i < newStory.length` instead of `i <= newStory.length`, this is a pattern for loop an array preventing index out of bound.

Comment: Let me try this, one sec :)

Comment: try let overusedWords[j] = 1 it will not work and show same error

Comment: Because this isn't the only issue with the code, right now it runs forever. Both `<=` should be `<`

Comment: what is other issue? he only need change to overusedWords[j] = overusedWords[j] + 1;

Comment: he only ask why Why isn't this possible: let array[j] = array[j] + 1;? did you focus on the question? updated answer for your case Yannick K

Comment: I would assume a "good answer" would attempt to fix someone's broken code, even if the question doesn't specifically ask about that part of the code. But sure, I'll remove the downvote.